# Swift can't start AVCaptureSession

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

I want to set up camera in my app and here is all my code

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

guard let captureDevcie = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevcie) else { return }
captureSession.addInput(input)

captureSession.startRunning()
```

In infoplist i have set `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`,but when i start up the app it doesn't ask any permission.It prints this long error in console and that's all

```
2017-08-21 12:47:43.686794+0400 Object Detection ML[26844:15000001] [] captureSourceSimulator_CopyProperty signalled err=-12784 (kCMBaseObjectError_PropertyNotFound) (Unknown property) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2027.1.4/Celeste/Sources/Capture/CaptureSource/FigCaptureSourceSimulator.m:266
2017-08-21 12:47:43.687091+0400 Object Detection ML[26844:15000001] [] <<<< AVCaptureFigVideoDevice >>>> -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice _copyFigCaptureSourceProperty:]_block_invoke: (0x7f9b27c06cf0) Copy(AttributesDictionary) failed (-12784)
2017-08-21 12:47:43.687710+0400 Object Detection ML[26844:15000001] [] captureSourceSimulator_CopyProperty signalled err=-12784 (kCMBaseObjectError_PropertyNotFound) (Unknown property) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2027.1.4/Celeste/Sources/Capture/CaptureSource/FigCaptureSourceSimulator.m:266
2017-08-21 12:47:43.688007+0400 Object Detection ML[26844:15000001] [] <<<< AVCaptureFigVideoDevice >>>> -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice _copyFigCaptureSourceProperty:]_block_invoke: (0x7f9b27c06cf0) Copy(Formats) failed (-12784)
```

`Object Detection ML` is the project's name.What may be the problem here?

Comment: have you check on device?

Comment: @NishantBhindi what do you mean by "check on device"?